# Variable In A Trigger Throws Nothing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, return-value

I'm trying to create a trigger that discounts points but one of my variables are not getting data, this is the variable:

```
DECLARE 
 @Puntos INT

SET @Puntos = (SELECT cli.U_PUNTOS FROM CLIENTE cli WHERE cli.CLIENTE = (SELECT TOP 1 pos.CLIENTE FROM INSERTED I INNER JOIN DOCUMENTO_POS pos ON pos.DOCUMENTO = I.DOCUMENTO))
```

I'm printing the value in the `raiserror` but there is no value.

However, I try this query with a specific value in the where and it has a value:

```
SELECT cli.U_PUNTOS FROM CLIENTE cli WHERE cli.CLIENTE = (SELECT TOP 1 pos.CLIENTE FROM DOCUMENTO_POS pos WHERE pos.CLIENTE = '74290451')
```

This throws:

> ***U_PUNTOS*** 
>
> 100.00000000

Another thing that I see is that when the variable in the trigger is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 cli.U_PUNTOS FROM CLIENTE cli
```

It has a value and I can see it in the `raiserror` message.

***UPDATE***

- The tables and columns involved are:

TABLE: CLIENTE 
COLUMNS: 
CLIENTE   VARCHAR(20)  PK 
NOMBRE    VARCHAR(150)    
U_PUNTOS  DECIMAL(28,8)   

TABLE: DOCUMENTO_POS 
COLUMNS: 
DOCUMENTO        VARCHAR(50)  PK  
CLIENTE          VARCHAR(20)  FK  
NOMBRE_CLIENTE   VARCHAR(150)     

TABLE: DOC_POS_LINEA  
COLUMNS:
DOCUMENTO   VARCHAR(50)  PK, FK  
ARTICULO    VARCHAR(20)  FK      
CANTIDAD    DECIMAL(28,8)

- Sample data of the tables:

TABLE: CLIENTE

```
CLIENTE     NOMBRE                      U_PUNTOS
10271085    ZAMORA GARCIA, VICTORIA      50.00000000
74290451    DANIEL ALONSO CABRERA DIAZ  100.00000000
```

TABLE: DOCUMENTO_POS

```
DOCUMENTO       CLIENTE     NOMBRE_CLIENTE
B044-00000112   10271085    ZAMORA GARCIA, VICTORIA
B002-00000346   74290451    DANIEL ALONSO CABRERA DIAZ
B005-00000003   74290451    DANIEL ALONSO CABRERA DIAZ
```

TABLE: DOC_POS_LINEA

```
DOCUMENTO       ARTICULO    CANTIDAD
B016-00011226   0779999017  1.00000000
```

The trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [EXACTUS].[TR_REST_PTS_PROM_NAVID] 
ON  [EXACTUS].[DOC_POS_LINEA]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE 
     @Puntos INT,
     @Cliente  VARCHAR(20),
     @Cantidad INT,
     @Mensaje VARCHAR(20)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @Puntos = (SELECT cli.U_PUNTOS FROM CLIENTE cli WHERE cli.CLIENTE = (SELECT TOP 1 pos.CLIENTE FROM INSERTED I INNER JOIN DOCUMENTO_POS pos ON pos.DOCUMENTO = I.DOCUMENTO))
    SET @Cliente = (SELECT pos.CLIENTE FROM INSERTED I INNER JOIN DOCUMENTO_POS pos ON pos.DOCUMENTO = I.DOCUMENTO);
    SET @Cantidad = (SELECT I.CANTIDAD FROM INSERTED I)
    
    IF (SELECT I.ARTICULO FROM INSERTED I) IN ('0779999047')
    BEGIN
        IF (@Cantidad) * 250 <= @Puntos
        BEGIN
            BEGIN
                UPDATE CLIENTE SET U_PUNTOS = (CASE WHEN U_PUNTOS IS NULL THEN NULL Else U_PUNTOS - 250 * @Cantidad END) WHERE CLIENTE = @Cliente;
            END
        END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('El cliente no puede canjear el pavo navideño al no contar con puntos suficientes.',16,1);
            END
    END
    ELSE IF (SELECT I.ARTICULO FROM INSERTED I) IN ('0999999017','0999999019')
    BEGIN
        IF (@Cantidad) * 70 <= @Puntos
        BEGIN
            BEGIN
                UPDATE CLIENTE SET U_PUNTOS = (CASE WHEN U_PUNTOS IS NULL THEN NULL Else U_PUNTOS - 70 * @Cantidad END) WHERE CLIENTE = @Cliente;
            END
        END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('El cliente no puede canjear el panetón al no contar con puntos suficientes.',16,1);
            END
    END
    ELSE IF (SELECT I.ARTICULO FROM INSERTED I) IN ('0779999017','0999999022')
    SET @Mensaje = @Puntos
    BEGIN
        IF (@Cantidad) * 60 <= @Puntos
        BEGIN
            BEGIN
                UPDATE CLIENTE SET U_PUNTOS = (CASE WHEN U_PUNTOS IS NULL THEN NULL Else U_PUNTOS - 60 * @Cantidad END) WHERE CLIENTE = @Cliente;
            END
        END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR(@Mensaje,16,1);
            END
    END
END
```

The variable @Mensaje contains the value of the variable @Puntos and I print it in the last `raiserror`

About multiple rows, the table DOC_POS_LINEA could receive more than 1 row because is the detail of a sale.

If you need more information, please tell me for update my post. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show your table structure, some sample data, and your complete trigger code. Also it looks to me that your trigger is broken - it doesn't appear to handle the case when Inserted has multiple rows in it?

Comment: Your trigger is fundamentally broken and needs to be rewritten. You suffer from the common problem of assuming that the statement affected a SINGLE row - which is not safe. There are many other issues that you really need to address - developing good habits is not easy and following patterns developed years ago is not a good habit.

Comment: As SMor said, this is a rewrite job... there are plenty of examples on this site of how to write triggers using proper set based logic. You can test outside a trigger by creating temp tables to simulate the logic.